# How to access nested object value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have generic object

```
type Section = {
  [key:string]: {
    [key:string]: string;
  }
}
```

```
const data: Sections = {
  first: {
    valueA: "1234",
    valueB: "5678"
 },
 second: {
    valueA: "0000",
    valueB: "4444"
 }
}
```

how can I create function to access nested value based on key. For example I want something like this `getSection("first", "valueA")`.

I created function with typed first argument

```
const getSection = (value: keyof typeof sections) => {
  console.log(value)
}
```

But don't know how to make second argument strong typed

Comment: You can't, with the type you've used for `Section`. It allows any string as a key at both levels. Does `Section` **have** to be defined as you've shown?

Comment: Is it `Section` or `Sections`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, with the type you've used for `Section` (or is it `Sections`? you've used both in your question). It allows any string as a key at both levels.

But if you define `data` using `as const` so that the types of things aren't broadened, and then define `Section` as `typeof data`, you can do it using generics:

```typescript
const data = {
    first: {
        valueA: "1234",
        valueB: "5678",
    },
    second: {
        valueA: "0000",
        valueB: "4444",
    },
} as const;
type Sections = typeof data;

const getSection = <OuterKey extends keyof Sections, InnerKey extends keyof Sections[OuterKey]>(
    outerKey: OuterKey,
    innerKey: InnerKey,
) => {
    return data[outerKey][innerKey];
};

// Works
console.log(getSection("second", "valueB"));
//                     v−−− Error: Argument of type '"third"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"first" | "second"'.
console.log(getSection("third", "x"));
//                               v−−− Error: Argument of type '"valueC"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"valueB" | "valueA"'.
console.log(getSection("second", "valueC"));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

---

**If** `Sections` is a type you can't change, you can still allow `data` to have a more narrow type while guaranteeing it still matches the `Sections` type via the new(ish) [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```typescript
type Section = {
    [key:string]: {
        [key:string]: string;
    }
};

const data = {
    first: {
        valueA: "1234",
        valueB: "5678",
    },
    second: {
        valueA: "0000",
        valueB: "4444",
    },
} as const satisfies Section;

const getSection = <OuterKey extends keyof typeof data, InnerKey extends keyof typeof data[OuterKey]>(
    outerKey: OuterKey,
    innerKey: InnerKey,
) => {
    return data[outerKey][innerKey];
};

// Works
console.log(getSection("second", "valueB"));
//                     v−−− Error: Argument of type '"third"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"first" | "second"'.
console.log(getSection("third", "x"));
//                               v−−− Error: Argument of type '"valueC"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"valueB" | "valueA"'.
console.log(getSection("second", "valueC"));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDGwCWB7AdlAvFA3gKCkKgG0BrCEALgGdgAnJNAcwF1LcCiuyKb7HW7Wg2YBuToQC+eSeLzx0tKABMAhsFVYOXAGZI6tdvi5cAbqoA2AVwgBBdgCIAjACYAzABYHAGgknz1hAAQo4ArABsAOwAHD5+kr5c1AjoykZ+ZpY29lAOAAwFeXEmRAE2IbkeVV6JRAkyUKrUUApoStTqSNR6EM1wiKhocq1KTBDA-cjoWgA8APJWwBB0ANIUUBAAHktoys3kICg6UKCQRyrqqt5QAJJoaMtrIBvbELv7FOenEOdqGsQLJarCgsAB8AAo-ChFo9eFBAbCQLVCIwHsCqLd7ojfABKLCg7REOjjKx0DB-VTEaFAp4sYioxEscSyPB4AD0bKgAHUUHRSNR5IoUBYIAA6CwoJjgsYTBBTNDghzJVrKHy5MrBBw4nHiDklfUG0yAJCITVAAKJ0Oi89i2OhMKwAWzewCgX3A0AA5A5gAALfSqj1QLpQNAoF1NahIJhoVQAIxFJxQUDAqjoqidQNdx2+UC9egMwAcUAAPrllakHB7RYK2sKxRKpTLJoNFb7-WqHJstTr2ZyDf2B6UTUbzZbrVBbfanWgXW7ILmHBqAMKVoPNUPh6iR6NxhPAJMptMZ5ZZk7uhcaoJF0uLrJ2SvVkZ18WS6XjZvoRXl3Yd5fd8RAA)

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` should have its own type:

```
const data = {
  first: {
    valueA: "1234",
    valueB: "5678"
 },
 second: {
    valueA: "0000",
    valueB: "4444"
 }
} satisfies Section
// data is now {first:{valueA:string,valueB:string}, ...}
```

Then you can `keyof` its type

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?
[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDKsDG4CWB7AdgZ3gLzwDeo88A2gNayQBcu4ATutgOYC6dJZ5lN9Ri3Zd4Q1mwDcvAL6g5YEChyMxqDCsI8Q5AGbomjbqR18AbgEMANgFdYAQW4AiAIwAmAMwAWJwBpe5Ja2sABCzgCsAGwA7AAcTrL%20prioOAAmxgHm1naO8E4ADEUFflmBOaHOXtU%20svLwFvjKeOCgoAD07fBssODIaFjYABRO%20obgfvlBuU4AlG0gujbYAzjdvf0a2AA8ACq%208ADS8LAAHuCw2Gn4Api68LsAfEMpq3jc%20-AC3IcHAm7cW73XYUQ4cWbacjNXCYKywAB0VkwbCGAnmIAUoB6fXUgxeuJUB1GBkYkyc0wccwWQA)

```
type Sections = {
  [key:string]: {
    [key:string]: string;
  }
}

const sections = {
  first: {
    valueA: "1234",
    valueB: "5678"
  },
  second: {
      valueA: "0000",
      valueB: "4444"
  }
} as const;

function getSection<T, K extends keyof T>(sections: T, key: K, key2: keyof T[K]) {
  console.log(key)
}

getSection(sections, "first", "valueA")
```